# WSO2 stream processor, json error "contains missing attributes" with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, stream-processing, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am using kafka to get data to WSO2 stream processor in Json format, but I am getting the error "contains missing attributes.Hence dropping the message" error on every json file I send to wso2 kafka topic.
I have downloaded latest JSON siddhi connector "https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/analyticsextension/details/0e6a6b38-f1d1-49f5-a685-e8c16741494d" and replaced in my wso2/lib directory.

I don't get any error if I run this on simulator but only when events are published to kafka topic manually.

Below is my WSO2 Stream processor code:

```
@App:name('Transaction json')
/*

TransactionStream definition. It receives events from "kafka_topic" in json format.

*/

@source(type = 'kafka', topic.list = 'kafka_topic', partition.no.list = '0', threading.option = 'single.thread', group.id = 'group', bootstrap.servers = 'localhost:9092', 
    @map(type = 'json',enclosing.element='$',
    @attributes(code = "code", name = "name",desc = "desc",transRefId ="transRefId",origAmount ="origAmount",amount = "amount",currency = "currency",requestId = "requestId",redeemedCashcode = "redeemedCashcode", sender_id ="sender.id",sender_name = "sender.name", sender_phone = "sender.phone",sender_pocket = "sender_pocket",sender_client = "sender.client",receiver_id = "receiver.id",receiver_name = "receiver.name",receiver_phone = "receiver.phone",receiver_pocket = "receiver.pocket",receiver_client = "receiver.client",beneficiary_phone = "beneficiary.phone",receiver_client = "receiver.client",beneficiary_phone = "beneficiary.phone",beneficiary_name = "beneficiary.name",beneficiary_nric = "beneficiary.nric",depositor_phone = "depositor.phone",depositor_name = "depositor.name",depositor_nric = "depositor.nric",offer = "offer",service = "service" , message = "message",status = "status",processedBy_id = "processedBy.id",processedBy_name = "processedBy.name",processedBy_phone = "processedBy.phone",processedBy_client = "processedBy.client",processedBy_owner = "processedBy.owner",processedAt = "processedAt",fees_debitFee = "fees.debitFee",fees_creditFee = "fees.creditFee",deviceId = "deviceId",isRefund ="isRefund",oldTransRefId = "oldTransRefId",linkBankTrans_err = "linkBankTrans.err",linkBankTrans_message = "linkBankTrans.message",linkBankTrans_data = "linkBankTrans.data",linkBankTrans_status = "linkBankTrans.status",linkBankTrans_request_url = "linkBankTrans.request.url",linkBankTrans_request_requestParams = "linkBankTrans.request.requestParams",linkBankTrans_action = "linkBankTrans.action",bankAccountNo = "bankAccountNo",transType = "transType",devGrp = "devGrp",createdAt = "createdAt",updatedAt = "updatedAt")))
define stream TransactioninputStream (code string, name string, desc string, transRefId string, origAmount float, amount float, currency string, requestId string, redeemedCashcode string, sender_id string, sender_name string, sender_phone string, sender_pocket string, sender_client string, receiver_id string, receiver_name string, receiver_phone string, receiver_client string, beneficiary_phone string, beneficiary_name string, beneficiary_nric string, depositor_phone string, depositor_name string,depositor_nric  string, offer string, service string, message string, status string, processedBy_id string, processedBy_name string, processedBy_phone string, processedBy_client string, processedBy_owner string,processedAt string, fees_debitFee float, fees_creditFee float, deviceId string, isRefund string, oldTransRefId string, linkBankTrans_err string, linkBankTrans_message string, linkBankTrans_data string, linkBankTrans_status string, linkBankTrans_request_url string, linkBankTrans_request_requestParams string, linkBankTrans_action string, bankAccountNo string, transType string, devGrp string, createdAt string);
```

Reference Json:

```
{
  "cd": "acb235dd",
  "name": "Newtest",
  "desc": "testing env",
  "ref": "3232d3dew3",
  "ora": 500000,
  "amount": 500000,
  "curr": "INR",
  "sen": {
    "id": "fdgdfgv",
    "name": "dao",
    "phone": "8268826483",
    "pocket": "bde4gvfdgd3fd",
    "cl": "try"
  },
  "rec": {
    "id": "fsfsgfs3322",
    "name": "mmv",
    "phone": "76288373",
    "pocket": "null",
    "cl": "test"
  },
  "bef": {
    "phone": "null",
    "name": "null",
    "ic": "null"
  },
  "dep": {
    "phone": "null",
    "name": "null",
    "ic": "null"
  },
  "offer": "htgdte44",
  "service": "gdrgdrgdv34",
  "status": "done",
  "prb": {
    "id": "fdgdgd",
    "name": "test",
    "phone": "frgvrd",
    "cl": "test",
    "owner": "null"
  },
  "processedAt": {
    "$date": "2019-09-19T10:17:05.377+0000"
  },
  "fees": {
    "debitFee": 0,
    "creditFee": 0,
  },
  "dId": "vdsvdd433",
  "anumb": "xxxx6452",
  "ttype": "normal",
  "devGrp": 0,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2019-09-19T10:17:05.381+0000"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2019-09-19T10:17:05.381+0000"
  },
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5d8355a1a3b8053cb768eea8"
  },
  "bankTrans": {
    "err": "0",
    "message": "successfully!",
    "data": "fbsvbsgfiyshiu39",
    "status": 0,
    "request": {
      "url": "http://localhost/testing",
      "requestParams": "89743874023804832084093278327082384-329-4932-r-98-384-83-24"
    },
    "action": "testing"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when some of the attributes are missing in the message. Here in the sample message, there is no code attribute. That's why the messages are dropped. However, you can ask siddhi JSON mapper to process messages even if attributes are missing using, `fail.on.missing.attributes=false`. Please see API docs of JSON mapper https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi-map-json/api/5.0.5/

Comment: Even after specifying  "fail.on.missing.attributes=false" , kafka json sink and source are giving the same error of contains missing attributes.

Comment: Ah sorry, seems the correct param is  `fail.on.missing.attribute`. However, keep in mind, here the event will be triggered with null values for the attributes that are not present

Comment: Hi,
I have one more question. It's quite silly but can we use wso2 stream processor to save data directly into Mysql. Wso2 doesn't support Mysql with "@ sink" , can we do it with "@ source" ?

Comment: Yes you can, you have to use event table(https://siddhi.io/en/v4.x/docs/query-guide/#table) interface with @store annotation https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi-store-rdbms/api/5.1.6/